# what is the required order for S3 element values when making a Post request?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm trying to upload a file to S3 by doing :

```
r_response = requests.post(presigned_post["url"], json=presigned_post["fields"], files=files)
```

but I'm getting the following error:

> Bucket POST must contain a field named 'key'.  If it is specified, please check the order of the fields.

But I'm definitely including a `key` value.  One other answer I saw recommended using a `OrderedDict` which I'm trying to do, but looking through the S3 documentation below, I don't see where it specifies a required order for they key,value data when making the request.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTForms.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-authentication-HTTPPOST.html

Anyone have any advice?

Boto3 returns a dictionary with the element values in the following order: `x-amz-signature`, `x-amz-algorithm`, `key`, `x-amz-credential`, `policy`, and `x-amz-date` and I'm just using the same dictionary.

```
def get_signed_request(title, type, track_id, file):
    S3_BUCKET = os.environ.get('S3_BUCKET')
    file_name = title
    file_type = type
    region = 'us-east-1'
    s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name=region, config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'))

    presigned_post = s3.generate_presigned_post(
        Bucket = S3_BUCKET,
        Key = file_name
    )

    files = {'file': file}

    r_response = requests.post(presigned_post["url"], json=presigned_post["fields"], files=files)
```

Printing the contents of `presigned_post` shows the key:

```
 {'fields': {'x-amz-signature': '26eff5417d0d11a25dd294b059a088e2be37a97f14713962f4240c9f4e33febb', 'x-amz-algorithm': 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256', 'key': u'sound.m4a', 'x-amz-credential': u'<AWSAccessID>/20161011/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request', 'policy': u'eyJjb25kaXRpb25zIjogW3siYnVja2V0IjogImZ1dHVyZWZpbGVzIn0sIHsia2V5IjogInNvdW5kLm00YSJ9LCB7IngtYW16LWFsZ29yaXRobSI6ICJBV1M0LUhNQUMtU0hBMjU2In0sIHsieC1hbXotY3JlZGVudGlhbCI6ICJBS0lBSTdLRktCTkJTNEM0VktKQS8yMDE2MTAxMS91cy1lYXN0LTEvczMvYXdzNF9yZXF1ZXN0In0sIHsieC1hbXotZGF0ZSI6ICIyMDE2MTAxMVQyMDM4NDlaIn1dLCAiZXhwaXJhdGlvbiI6ICIyMDE2LTEwLTExVDIxOjM4OjQ5WiJ9', 'x-amz-date': '20161011T203849Z'}, 'url': u'https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname'}
```

Comment: Why are you using `requests` and not the ˋBoto3` lib (which is now a de facto standard). You have an example here: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/quickstart.html#using-boto-3. Example: `s3.Bucket('my-bucket').put_object(Key='test.jpg', Body=data)`.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE I'm eventually going to be doing this on my frontend, so I'm testing it out on my backend at first.  In order to do it on my front end client I need to generate a pre-signed post.  I'm doing almost exactly what is in their documentation: https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/s3.html#generating-presigned-posts

Comment: What code are you using to create `presigned_post['url']` and `presigned_post['fields']`?

Comment: @kichik the boto3 function 'generate_presigned_post()' generates the fields.  https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/s3.html#generating-presigned-posts

Comment: Right, but how exactly are you calling it? The error suggests you're not passing `Key` in there.

Comment: @kichik I updated my post with the code.  `key` is definitely there.

Comment: I am not sure `genreate_presigned_post()` can be used for JSON posting. It is expected that those fields are used in a form. Try `generate_presigned_url()` instead. It gives you just one URL you post the file to without any other requirements. You will still have to make sure the content type you use is the same as the one you specified with `generate_presigned_url()` or else you'll get signature errors.

Comment: @kichik but can `generate_presigned_url()` be used to `POST`?  in the documentation they use `generate_presigned_url()` for `GET` and `generate_presigned_post()` for `POST`.

Comment: I use it successfully with `ClientMethod='put_object'` and `PUT` method. As long as the method matches the method, you should be good.

Comment: would your request look like `requests.post(pre_signed_url, data, file)`?  But you dont need the data argument anymore right?

Comment: Should be `requests.put(pre_signed_url, open(file_path))`. It's not expecting normal form multi-part upload.

Comment: @kichik I tired it out last night and got the same error back that I got when using the `generate_presigned_post()` `The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.`  I guess `boto3` isn't giving me the right signature.

Comment: Did you use the same content type on both the request and the signature?

Comment: @kichik Not sure I follow what you're asking.  I provide the file type as `audio/m4a`.  What `boto3` returns is what I use.  I don't add content type manually in my post request.

Comment: Then you should. You should manually set `Content-Type` on your request to make sure it exactly matches what you gave `boto3` when generating the URL.

Comment: @kichik add "content-type" to my `presigned_post["fields"]`

Comment: No, it's a header.

Comment: @kichik Ill test it out.  I have a question for this issue up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40007086/boto3-signature-doesnt-match-with-s3

Comment: @kichik I added `Content-Type` so my header looks like  `{'Accept': '*/*', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.11.1', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-Type': 'audio/m4a', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Content-Length': '81051'}`.  Now I get `Error><Code>PreconditionFailed</Code><Message>At least one of the pre-conditions you specified did not hold</Message><Condition>Bucket POST must be of the enclosure-type multipart/form-data</Condition>`

Comment: You are still using `POST` instead of `PUT`.

Comment: @kichik `PUT` results in `<Error><Code>MalformedXML</Code><Message>The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema</Message>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was originally doing:

```
r_response = requests.post(presigned_post["url"], json=presigned_post["fields"], files=files)
```

I changed the `json` to `data` and it worked:

```
r_response = requests.post(presigned_post["url"], data=presigned_post["fields"], files=files)
```

Unfortunately, I was dealt another error:

`<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>`